# Python namedtuple fields extension

Tags: python, data-structures

I am using namedtuples instead of dictionaries because I find it more elegant to access the fields using namedtuples. However, when I want to add more fields to a given namedtuple I do the following, and I was wondering whether there is a simpler way to add fields to a nametuple:

```
Trip = namedtuple("Trip", ["longitute", "latitude", "timestamp"]) 
trips_arr = [Trip(longitude=1, latitude=2, timestamp=1), 
            Trip(longitude=2, latitude=2, timestamp=2)]

ExtentedTrip = namedtuple("ExtentedTrip", trips_arr[0]._fields + ["person"])
Person = namedtuple("Person", ["person"])

extented_trips = []
for trip in trips_arr:
    person = Dist(distance=get_person())
    extented_trips.append(ExtentedTrip(*(trip + person)))
```

Comment: Does `__fields__` work?  What version of python are you using?  AFAIK, namedtuple uses `Trip._fields` -- And accessing that on the class `Trip` would probably be more clear than picking it up from an instance.  Aside from that, I think you need to define a bit more what your requirements are.  Do you need a subclass of `Trip` or just another named tuple with a few extra properties?  Does the class need to define slots or should it support assignment of _any_ attribute?  Realistically, What you have is probably about as good as it gets (other than possibly factoring it out into a function)

Comment: Thanks, `__fields__` worked because I actually had a row from a spark dataframe and not nametuples, and there I needed `__fields__` instead of `_fields`. To access the fields of the namedtuple, I have to use `Trip._fields` as you pointed out. I edited the example.

Comment: I'd like to mention the `Bunch` class: https://github.com/dsc/bunch . It is like a dict, but its items can be accessed like attributes. But unlike nameduple it is mutable.